# Show ringtones and books in iTunes library

Tags: itunes

In my iTunes (12.3.2) I want to have ringtones and books show up under library.  But only Music & Purchased shows up under library. I went to iTunes preferences/general and did not get the option to have those two ringtones and books show up.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ringtones are called Tones in my version of iTunes (12.3.2.35), and are already shown on the top left of your screen capture.

If not, you can click the ··· menu and edit it to make them always visible.

[image: ringtones itunes]

Purchased books and audiobooks are shown on the iBooks app on OS X and iOS.